# sample program giving syntax error in visual studio

Tags: c++

```
#define DH_CONTLINE //
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("%s \n", DH_CONTLINE);
   return 0;
}
```

In the above program showing error at line :5
error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: Can you please post code that is properly formatted?

Comment: DH_CONTLINE isn't a string literal, const char* or char array - why are you trying to pass it to a `%s` format specifier?  Anyway - you're using C++ - try `std::cout << ` syntax for your output....

Comment: Hello Tony if u use cout also same syntax error showing

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("%s \n", //);
   return 0;
}
```

That explains the compiler error.